# Simulating noise in computed tomography reconstruction

Tags: noise, reconstruction

In the research of the computed tomography (CT) reconstruction, one needs to simulate the noise during CT projection and capturing. Then, my questions are:

1. How about the proper noise type?
2. How to add the noise, in the sinogram domain or the frequency domain?

Any reference materials are also preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest, and probably most straight forward way, seems to add the noise in the measurement domain, hence the sinogram.

Comment: Thank you. how about the noise type? Gaussian?

Comment: I don't know. I wouldn't expect Gaussian noise, since your detector cannot measure negative signals. I would expect it to be a Poisson-distribution.

Comment: thank you, can you recommend any references?

Comment: No, I can't. I would take a first step by googling *noise computer tomography* ;)

Comment: Thanks. I found a similar question: https://cn.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/315689

Comment: CT artifacts: Causes and reduction techniques - F. Edward Boas: [link](http://www.edboas.com/science/CT/0012.pdf)